# How to recover linux user password?

Tags: linux, password

I forgot my **user password** for my Linux and there is no permission to login as root. I don’t know how to recover it.

Comment: I know the root password but i forgot the user password. So i was unable to login and i tried using root login but it says no permission to login as adminstrator.

Comment: which version of linux is it ?

Comment: boss Gnu/linux 3.2.0

Comment: As you have mentioned that you know the `root` password but forgot your user password, then what you have to do is got to the terminal with `Alt + Ctrl + F1` key and login in the terminal as root. Once logged in as root now type `passwd <username>` where the <username> is your actual username. And it will prompt you to enter new password. Now once done you can switch back to desktop with `Alt + Ctrl + F7` key and try login with the new password, it will work. The reason you are not allowed to login to desktop as `root` is for security reasons. BOSS Linux is based on Debian GNU/linux.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're using Ubuntu (or similar) with no `root` password.

The easiest option would be to remove your user password, login with no password (easy!) and set a new one.

**Warning:** Only do this if you're in a reasonably safe environment (PC/laptop in home or office) etc - don't do it on a Internet connected, `ssh` enabled server especially if the username in question is something common (such as `admin`) as the short window without a password may allow unwanted access to your server.

To reset the password:

- Boot the computer with a LiveCD (any reasonable distro will do).
- Mount the system's root (`/`) partition somewhere (`/mnt` maybe) - make sure it's mounted read/write as you'll be editing a file on it.
- Edit `/etc/shadow` as user `root` (using `su` or `sudo`).
- Find the entry for your user and remove everything between the first and second colon (`:`) - it's a long string of random looking characters.
- Save the changes, unmount the partition and reboot into your normal system.
- Login with no password.
- Quickly set your user's password.
- Log out and in and check it works.

Comment: When i tried to open linux it is asking for password. How to login without password and i dont have cd-drive...... :(

Comment: Do you have a USB port? Create a bootable USB-stick instead of a CD.  The medium you used to install Linux may well work.

The idea is to boot with a CD or USB-stick Live distro, which don't have passwords to log in.  Once in, you can then manipulate the Linux installation on your hard-disk.

Comment: If there was a magic back-door, then there would be no point having a password. But there is a back-door, it is as described here, boot-up from a different media. (Having a bios password to stop user from selecting a different boot device can make this more secure.)